# Multipurposing a SSRS report with multivalued parameters

Tags: reporting-services, oracle10g, ssrs-2008-r2

here's the situation:

I have a report, that has 6 multivalue parameters and the job is to make parameters optional, so that main dataset resultset can be filtered by all or none parameters. Ie. it has to be possible to search for all Places in Place-table, that have Lamps value of 2 or 3. Or one specific place by name. Et cetera. 
There is quite a lot topics on optional parameters and I have read a lot and still can't get it to work. I have tried playing with default parameters, nvl:ing and some other things I have found on the Internet. Nothing seems to work.

Is this kind of thing even possible?

Comment: It should be very easy.  Multi-valued parameters have a built in "Select All" checkbox, so design your code so that if the user checks all Places, then all Places are selected in your SQL.

Comment: The problem with "Select All" is that maximum of 1000 parameter values is allowed and the list for this example Place-parameter is way larger, closer to 10000. Another thing, if I remember correctly, "Select All" won't include null values into result set?

Comment: See here, you can get around the 1000 value limit: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/040cbe81-df67-4bcc-8dfe-0eb469b72bbe/is-there-any-limitation-for-the-report-parameter-size-in-the-ssrs2008-r2-in-holding-multiple?forum=sqlreportingservices    And "select all" will do exactly that:  select all the checkboxes that are displayed in your parameter checklist.

Answer (score 0):

1. For the parameter query where you list the available values, do a union All with 'ALL' as 1 of the values/label. Put it at the top of the query and make it default if you wish.
2. Change your dataset query so it accepts ALL or IN. See below an example.

(
(@Client='All') OR
(@Client<>'All' AND @ClientType='Parent' AND par.CLIENT_CODE IN (SELECT parts FROM cmsts.[dbo].[fn_Split] (@Client,','))) OR
(@Client<>'All' AND @ClientType='Child' AND child.CLIENT_CODE IN (SELECT parts FROM cmsts.[dbo].[fn_Split] (@Client,',')))
)